# Have an entire <div> float right which contains a <p> element and a <a> element

Tags: css

I am trying to float an entire DIV to the right, where both containing elements P and A remain on the same line (now the A element moves below the P). How to get them on the same line together?
Fiddle[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/rabas007/g6m996m8/4/)

my HTML:

```
<div class="go-here"><p>Go here: </p><a href="www.placehold.it" target=
                        "_blank">Placehold</a></div>
```

and CSS

```
.go-here a:link {
    font-size:18px;
    color:#ED152F
}

.go-here p {
    font-size:12px;
    color:#000000
}

.go-here {
    float: right
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simple as putting `<a>` inside `<p>`:

```css
.go-here a:link {
    font-size:18px;
    color:#ED152F
}

.go-here p {
    font-size:12px;
    color:#000000
}

.go-here {
    float: right
}
Simple as putting <a> inside <p>:
```

```html
<div class="go-here"><p>Go here: <a href="www.placehold.it" target=
                        "_blank">Placehold</a></p></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Probably overkill, but I love flexbox magic:

```css
.go-here {
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
}
```

```css
.go-here {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  float: right;
}
.go-here a:link {
  font-size: 18px;
  color: #ED152F;
}
.go-here p {
  font-size: 12px;
  color: #000000;
}
```

```html
<div class="go-here">
  <p>Go here:</p>
  <a href="//example.com" target="_blank">Example</a>
</div>
```